# Extension to turn off the lights to any webpage element

Tags: web-browser, user-interface

When reading news articles, I'd like to hide all those sidebars and other items that scream for attention, I mean, to make everything black on the webpage except the **block of text** that I'm interested.

It would be a matter of clicking the extension button on the browser toolbar and selecting the HTML element that I want to read, this would create the Lights Off effect that I'm looking for. I'd prefer an extension for Chrome or Firefox, which I think are more cross-platform.

[image: Alloffthelights.js demonstration animated gif]

I only found ways to do this for **Video elements**, like [this](http://www.stefanvd.net/project/turnoffthelights.htm) and [this](http://www.turnoffthelights.com/) extensions, [this Q&A at Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/406976/turn-off-the-lights-on-any-website) and the [jQuery plugin](http://www.megaptery.com/allofthelights/) shown above.

Comment: For text elements, you can use [Reader](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/13366/6834). It doesn't exactly turn off the lights, but it removes all distracting content

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Turn Off the Lights API](http://www.turnoffthelights.com/APIwebsite.html), you can choose what must go not dark.

Or [open in the Turn Off the Lights option page](http://www.turnoffthelights.com/browser/mouse-actions.html), in the 3rd tab (advanced options) the mouse action → select self the area that should not be dark.