# Text or summary extractor from webpage

Tags: windows, gratis, firefox, scraping

I look for a software or add-on (Firefox) to extract the main text of a webpage.

For example for a Wikipedia article it must extract the article and omit the navigation bars, references or headers and footers.

If it can summarize a page that would be excellent.

- Free
- For Windows

Answer (score 2):

#### **[Reader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reader/)**

It is a **free Firefox add-on** that converts the webpage into an improved reading format. That includes:

- Stripping of Navigation panes, references, headers, and footers
- Customizable fonts, colors, and margins

Before and after screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that fits your usecase, but **[Readability](https://www.readability.com/shorten)** is an online service that can convert pages to more pleasant reading experience by extracting the main content. You can use it in Firefox as a [bookmarklet](https://www.readability.com/bookmarklets) or a [dedicated addon](https://www.readability.com/addons). Readability was AFAIK one of the first (if not the first) websites to provide such a service.